# Add an ID field that increments after the final submit

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have never done this before and am a little lost on the best approach.

I need a form that can be submitted to get a timestamp as to when that item was entered, easy enough, but also need it to have the same fileID as a other entries made until all entries have been made and the file closed. Then need the fileID to increment when they add entries for the next batch. The fileID is a way to track in sql what entries are tied to each file for calculation purposes.

I was think i could have a form with the required fields they submit and a next button. they use submit until they have completed the transactions for a file then next to bring up the calculations field which would have a submit and that would close the file and then need to increment the fileID

I haven't started this yet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the sql table I would like to have:

ID(auto incremented), fileID(with the default value from above), etc....

Comment: Use a [Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it is designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by retrieving the `fileID` on the first submit and then retaining it for all subsequent submits.

I'd probably do this by having a stored procedure that has a nullable parameter of `@fileID`, where if the parameter is not NULL it would be inserted, and if it was NULL then a new fileID would be generated. For retrieval of the new `fileID`, the stored procedure could have an output parameter for the newly generated `fileID`, or it could `SELECT` the item you just inserted (`ID`, `fileID`, and perhaps some other useful data) (I'd probably go with the latter).

As far as generating a new `fileID` goes, I'd probably have a separate table for "file" objects, which would also have an `IDENTITY` column. The other table would then have a `FOREIGN KEY` that references that table.